# How can I create pagination for a tumblr blog embedded on my personal website?

Tags: pagination, embedding, tumblr

I have embedded a Tumblr blog onto my website using the script provided in the goodies section of the Tumblr website as well as added the code to limit my posts to 5 of the most recent... indicated by ?num=5 at the end of the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.tumblr.com/js?num=5"></script>
```

What I am trying to do is build pagination for the blog on my personal website so that all posts are accessible to people wanting to view all of; even the oldest posts. I want to show 5 posts per page in the pagination. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have searched through this forum, Google, Tumblr and I even sent a question to the Tumblr support team but still haven't found the answer. THeir support team suggested I use frames but I don't know how to build that.

I hope someone can help!!

Thank's in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, as the Tumblr support suggested, is to use an iframe and simply embed the whole Tumbleblog inside. Like this:

```
<iframe src="http://website.tumblr.com" width="42px" height="42px">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp

The pagination has to take place on the actual Tumbleblog, like it is by default. Biggest downside is that it will be tricky to differ the design/layout and behaviour for the one that's embedded on your blog and the direct one (because it's the same, duh).

Comment: thank you for your response laander. I have imported some javascript from the goodies section of Tumblr on the botton right hand side of that section. Do you know how I might go about creating a pager for the content generated by that script in my text editor? What would I use? iframes? would I use JQuery pagination...having a hard time finding a tutorial to make this happen. I hope someone can help!!

Comment: I'm not certain that it is do-able with the javascript tumblr provides as it generates the output on it's side first and then serves it to you - if they don't provide a pagination feature, you will have to modify their output and implement it yourself. That might be tricky if you don't have much experience with javascript/jQuery. 

The simplest solution is to skip the javascript embed and use the iframe version I provided above. Simply put the HTML in your document (instead of the javascript embed) and your Tumblr should embed itself. Not ideal, I know, but the pure JS version is a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a jquery plugin for consuming your tumblr feed - I've just added pagination support.

Its called **jquery-tumblr** - https://github.com/alexhayes/jquery-tumblr

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting "Error: renderVideo is not defined" in JavaScript console and page gets stuck on "Loading..." (I can see there is some content from tumblr blog loaded in background though but never gets displayed)